# Time offset between two dates

Tags: java, date, kotlin, timezone

I have two timestamps and a localized date that I use to find the timezone offset and add it to these dates. How can I calculate the time offset between dates simpler? My method doesn't work with negative values (`if (tsOffset.toSecondOfDay() > 0` always `true`).

```
fun parseDateTime(startTs: Long, endTs: Long, localizedDateTime: String): Pair<String, String> {
    val dateUtcStart = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(startTs), ZoneOffset.UTC)
    val dateUtcEnd = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(endTs), ZoneOffset.UTC)

    val formatter = DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, dateUtcStart.year.toLong())
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E dd MMM hh:mm a"))
        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)

    val localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(localizedDateTime, formatter)

    val localTs = Timestamp.valueOf(localDateTime).time
    val tsOffset = LocalTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(localTs - startTs), ZoneOffset.systemDefault())
    val tzString = if (tsOffset.toSecondOfDay() > 0) "+$tsOffset" else tsOffset.toString()

    val startDate = dateUtcStart.toString() + tzString
    val endDate = dateUtcEnd.toString() + tzString

    return Pair(startDate, endDate)
}

@Test
fun parseDateTime() {
    val pair1 = parseDateTime(1626998400000, 1627005600000, "Fri 23 Jul 10:30 am")
    val pair2 = parseDateTime(1626998400000, 1627005600000, "Thu 22 Jul 11:30 pm")

    // pass
    assertEquals("2021-07-23T00:00+10:30", pair1.first)
    assertEquals("2021-07-23T02:00+10:30", pair1.second)
    // fails
    assertEquals("2021-07-23T00:00-00:30", pair2.first)
    assertEquals("2021-07-23T02:00-00:30", pair2.second)
}
```

Also I tried

```
val dur = Duration.between(dateUtcStart, localDateTime)
```

But don't sure how to convert it in the string or add to the dates properly.

Here `startTs` - start of an event timestamp. `endTs` - end of this event timestamp. `localizedDateTime` is used to show the start time in the actual time zone (real city) while timestamps show time in UTC. I need to extract this timezone from `localizedDateTime` and add it to start and end string dateTimes (`start = "2021-07-23T00:00+10:30", end = "2021-07-23T02:00+10:30"` for `startTs = 1626998400000` and `endTs = 1627005600000` accordingly).

Comment: I am confused by the role of your `localizedDateTime: String` input. That string is just a date and a time-of-day, without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. Yet you seem to assuming it represents a moment in some time zone. There are likely some serious flaws in your code. In particular, your usage of `LocalDateTime` and `Timestamp` classes is troubling.  I suggest you edit your question to explain more clearly about your original problem/goal, with less focus on your code. Specify carefully and precisely what each element of your inputs represents, and what you want as output.

Comment: `localizedDateTime` is used to show the time in the actual time zone (real city) while timestamps show time in UTC. All of them are 3-rd party input and I can't change them. My problem is: I have only these 3 dates and need to make a start and end dates with a time zone offset like in the test (e.g. `2021-07-23T00:00+10:30`)

Comment: Post clarifications as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: @Psijic update your question to describe what all this mess is doing - because your code is very much not helping, given that it's all over the place and abusing the java.time types. What are you trying to -DO-? What does 'start' and 'end' represent? What does that time represent? Example update: "Input A and B are epoch-millis. Input C is a string that represents the time at the same instant as epoch-milli A, in some unknown timezone. This method should derive that timezone, and then render epoch-milli A and B with a hardcoded formatting in that timezone. throw Exception X if impossible.

Comment: I take it that `startTs` (equal to 2021-07-23T00:00:00Z UTC) and `localizedDateTime` are supposed to denote the same point in time, and we need to calculate the UTC offset from this information? But for the result start date and time to be equal, it certainly needs to be `2021-07-23T10:30+10:30`, not `2021-07-23T00:00+10:30`.  What am I missing?

Comment: You’ve got a nasty corner case: New Year doesn’t happen at the same time in all time zones. So the year that you get from `dateUtcStart.year.toLong()` needs not be the year that was assumed in the string from a different time zone.

Comment: Another corner case: in that city the UTC offset may change between the start and the end timestamps (for example there may be a summer time transition), so even though you can calculate the correct UTC offset for the start date and time, you might have needed a different one for the end date and time. It seems we cannot know, so using the same offset again is probably the best guess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got an answer on the [Kotlin forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/time-offset-between-two-dates/22531/4):

```
    val duration = Duration.between(dateUtcStart, localDateTime)
    val offset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(duration.seconds.toInt())
    val startDate = dateUtcStart.atOffset(offset).toString()
    val endDate = dateUtcEnd.atOffset(offset).toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s no simpler than your code, on the contrary, but it fixes a couple of issues that you had.

Disclaimer: I haven’t got your `Pair` class and I cannot write nor run Kotlin. So I am printing the resulting strings from withint the method, which you will have to change for your purpose. And you will have to hand translate my Java.

```
private static void parseDateTime(long startTs, long endTs, String localizedDateTime) {
    // startTs and localizedDateTime are both representations of the event start time.
    // Use this information to obtain the UTC offset of the local time.
    
    Instant startInstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(startTs);
    OffsetDateTime startUtc = startInstant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    
    // Corner case: the local year may be different from the UTC year if the event is close to New Year.
    // Check whether this is the case. First get the UTC month and the local month.
    Month utcMonth = startUtc.getMonth();

    DateTimeFormatter baseSyntaxFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E dd MMM hh:mm a"))
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    Month localMonth = baseSyntaxFormatter.parse(localizedDateTime, Month::from);
    
    int utcYear = startUtc.getYear();
    int localYear;
    if (utcMonth.equals(Month.DECEMBER) && localMonth.equals(Month.JANUARY)) {
        // Local date is in the following year
        localYear = utcYear + 1;
    } else if (utcMonth.equals(Month.JANUARY) && localMonth.equals(Month.DECEMBER)) {
        localYear = utcYear - 1;
    } else {
        localYear = utcYear;
    }
    
    DateTimeFormatter finalFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(baseSyntaxFormatter)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, localYear)
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

    LocalDateTime startLocal = LocalDateTime.parse(localizedDateTime, finalFormatter);
    // Now calculate offset
    Duration durationOfOffset = Duration.between(startUtc.toLocalDateTime(), startLocal);
    ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(Math.toIntExact(durationOfOffset.getSeconds()));

    String startString = startLocal.atOffset(offset).toString();
    
    // Calculate end date and time
    String endString = Instant.ofEpochMilli(endTs)
            .atOffset(offset)
            .toString();

    System.out.format("%s - %s%n", startString, endString);
}
```

Let’s try it with your example data:

```
    parseDateTime(1_626_998_400_000L, 1_627_005_600_000L, "Fri 23 Jul 10:30 am");
    parseDateTime(1_626_998_400_000L, 1_627_005_600_000L, "Thu 22 Jul 11:30 pm");
```

Output:

> ```
> 2021-07-23T10:30+10:30 - 2021-07-23T12:30+10:30
> 2021-07-22T23:30-00:30 - 2021-07-23T01:30-00:30
> ```

You notice that the local start times are now 10:30 and 23:30 as in your input strings, which I believe corrects an error that you had.

Let’s also try an example that bridges New Year:

```
    Instant start = Instant.parse("2021-01-01T00:00:00Z");
    parseDateTime(start.toEpochMilli(),
            start.plus(2, ChronoUnit.HOURS).toEpochMilli(),
            "Thu 31 Dec 10:30 pm");
```

> ```
> 2020-12-31T22:30-01:30 - 2021-01-01T00:30-01:30
> ```

I have used basically the same way of calculating the offset that you present in your own answer.

### Issues with your code

First, as I said, the times that your unit test asserts do not agree with the times in your input. For the required output you have taken the UTC time of day and combined with the local offset, which gives a different point in time. A UTC offset is always used with a time of day at that offset (for UTC time of day one would use either offset `Z` or `+00:00`).

Consider having your method return a `Pair<OffsetDateTime, OffsetDateTime>`, not a `Pair<String, String>`. Strings are for presentation to the user and sometimes for data exchange. Inside your program you should use proper date-time objects, not strings.

As I said in the comments, New Year doesn’t happen at the same time in all time zones. So the year that you get from `dateUtcStart.year.toLong()` needs not be the year that was assumed in the string from a different time zone. My code takes this into account.

Don’t involve the `Timestamp` class. It’s poorly designed and long outdated. All it gives you is an extra conversion, hence extra complication.

Your basic problem was using a `LocalTime` for a duration that might be positive or negative. A `LocalTime`  is for a time of day, not for an amount of time. Your own solution already got rid of this problem.

This is wrong:

```
    val startDate = dateUtcStart.toString() + tzString
```

First, you should not want to use string manipulation for date and time math. The classes from java.time that you are using produce the string that you need more easily and with less risk of errors. Second, you have indeed got an error here: you are appending the calculated offset to a string that is in UTC, that is, assumes offset 0 (or `Z`). This was why you were in fact able to produce the incorrect results that your unit test expected.